# Как написать программу на Java работающую в интерфейсе Lotus Notes?

Tags: java, lotus-notes

Как написать программу на Java работающую в интерфейсе Lotus Notes?

Comment: Поясните что значит "работающую в интерфейсе Lotus Notes".

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте вот здесь - [Java-апплет: альтернатива встроенному представлению.](http://www.notesnet.ru/nn/notesnet.nsf/note/FC02BC1795DF4CC7C3256F6D005AAA4F)